# How to build a javascript that will return a json's objects containing specific name-value pairs

Tags: javascript, json

Using the below json as an example I want to write a js code that will only return the objects that contain specific name-value pairs:

Use case 1: return only the json objects containing the name-value pair "currency": "RON"

Use case 2 for nested pairs: return only the json objects containing the name-value pair "product_id": "1084929"

I want this done in plain js, not jquery.

Why would this be helpful for me? I sometimes have to validate large json files and it would help to "contract" the json to certain objects that interest me based on a specific use case.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "currency": "RUB",
            "status": "approved",
            "order_id": "Y3411851",
            "click_country_code": "RU",
            "positions": [
                {
                    "product_id": "1084929",
                    "amount": "2290.00"
                }
            ],

            "action_date": "2019-03-30 00:42:23",
            "processed": 1,
            "action_type": "sale",
            "action": "Оплаченный заказ"
        },
        {
            "currency": "RON",
            "status": "declined",
            "order_id": "Y3415290",
            "click_country_code": "RO",
            "positions": [
                {
                    "product_id": "1052297",
                    "amount": "4390.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Assuming that your 'results' array is inside an object called 'obj', first do:

```
let results = obj.results;
```

then,

case 1:

```
results.filter(obj=>obj.currency === "RON")
```

case 2:

```
results.filter(
  obj =>
    Array.isArray(obj.positions) &&
    obj.positions.some(
      position => position && position.product_id === "1084929"
    )
);
```